# Why this code doesn't work? :(

Tags: wpf, datagridview, combobox

```
<dg:DataGrid  Name="gridList" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                 
               ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsInTable}" HeadersVisibility="Column" >
   <dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
      <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemDetails" >
         <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="5" Background="Azure" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
               <ComboBox Name="cboxDepartment" SelectedItem="{Binding Department}"   DisplayMemberPath="Desc" ItemsSource="{Binding DeptosInTable}" ></ComboBox>
            </StacPanel>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="DEPARTMENT" Binding="{Binding Department}" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Department is a property in a class. DeptosInTable is a ObservableCollection with 2 properties: ID and Desc.

Comment: Please tell us what excactly is not working

Comment: When select an item in combobox, doesn't binding with Datagridtextcolumn, and when a datagrid loaded, the combobox doesnot show the correct value (should be Department value)

Comment: When a choose an item in combobox, show a class name in Department

Answer (score 2):

One error you have made (I'm not sure if it's the only one):

```
        </StacPanel>
```

Should be:

```
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: what'a catch, you are a bio-parser ;)

Comment: This is not a problem. It was typing.